# Renesas GCC linker error with shared code

Tags: c, gcc, compilation, renesas-rx

I'm using [GCC for Renesas](https://gcc-renesas.com/) with Renesas's E2 Studio IDE (v.6.2.0). Not that
it should matter, but I've also used Applilet3 (v.3.08.01.05) to generate
board support files and peripheral drivers.

When I attempt to build, I get the following errors...

```
'Invoking Linker'
rl78-elf-gcc (......object files and flags.......)
./src/r_main.o: In function `main':

<path_to_git_repo_dir>\src\<project_name>\HardwareDebug/../src/r_main.c:86: undefined reference to `_common_lib_a_init'
<path_to_git_repo_dir>\src\<project_name>\HardwareDebug/../src/r_main.c:89: undefined reference to `_common_lib_b_init'

collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
makefile:67: recipe for target 'my_project.elf' failed
make: *** [my_project.elf] Error 1
```

## Project Setup

I have some source code shared between projects in a "lib" folder. In 
`main()` I call some initialize functions for these "libraries", as
you can see from the errors. I don't understand why the compile
process works and yet this fails.

My source tree layout looks like this...

```
git-repo-dir/
    .git/
    doc/
    lib/
        my_lib_a/
            common_lib_a.h
            common_lib_a.c
        my_lib_b/
            common_lib_b.h
            common_lib_b.c
    src/
        my_project/
            .cproj
            .project
            applilet3_config.cgp
            src/
            generate/
```

I added the library source code to my E2 Studio project by...

- Right-clicking on the project name in E2's "Project Explorer" pane
- Clicking `Import` and select `File System`
- Browse to `get-repo-dir` and select (single-click) the `lib` folder
- Check the box on the left pane to include all files in `lib`
- Ensure "Create top-level folder" is selected
- Click "Advanced"
- Check the box for "Create links in workspace" and "Create virtual folders" and "Create link locations relative to:"  is `PROJECT_LOC`
- Finish

Then I add the include paths for the libraries to the build settings...

- Right-clicking on the project name in E2's "Project Explorer" pane
- Select "Properties"
- Select `C/C++ General > Paths and Symbols`
- Ensure configuration is the current/active one
- Select the "GNU C" language
- Click "Add" to add the following

  - `"${ProjDirPath}/../../lib/my_lib_a"`
  - `"${ProjDirPath}/../../lib/my_lib_b"`
- Apply
- Verify these paths are visible in `C/C++ Build > Settings > Compiler > Includes`

So in E2 Studio, the Project Explorer shows..

```
Archives/           (a virtual folder)
Includes/           (a virtual folder/list)
src/
generate/
lib/                (the virtual lib folder I added)
    my_lib_a/
    my_lib_b/
```

#### Any ideas why I'm getting a linker error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually noticed that the build log didn't contain any C files from the `lib/` folder.

The solution was simple. In E2 Studio, in the Project Explorer pane, I dragged the `lib/` folder in to (on top of) the `src/` folder.

Now the structure in Project Explorer looks like this:

```
Archives/           (a virtual folder)
Includes/           (a virtual folder/list)
src/
    lib/            (the virtual lib folder I added)
        my_lib_a/
        my_lib_b/
generate/
```

Evidently E2 Studio does not put source code that's outside of the `src/` directory in the autogenerated make file. Or maybe there's some setting I missed. Nonetheless, since the C code wasn't compiled, there was no object file to link against, hence the linker error.